# Type 'Element[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Element': type, props, key

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the standard arrow map ES7 function with Typescript and React environment:

```
 const getItemList: Function = (groups: any[]): JSX.Element => 
  group.map((item: any, i: number) => {
    const itemCardElemProps = { handleEvents: () => {}, ...item}
    return <Item key={`${item.id}_${i}`} {...itemCardElemProps} />
  })
```

and get the error:

```
TS2739: Type 'Element[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Element': type, props, key
```

Version: typescript 3.5.3

Answer (score 85):

You could always just send back a single JSX.Element as a fragment, too:

```js
interface IOptions {
   options: string[]
}

const CardArray: React.FC<IOptions> = ({ options }) => {
   return <>{options.map(opt => opt)}</>
}
```

This way you're matching the returned type and it won't affect your markup.

Comment: there is cases where it causes error for example, try to send fragment to a MUI Select element as a list of MenuItem... this is not good for all solutions.

Answer (score 40):

To fix the error, it is necessary to change type of the function output from `JSX.Element` to `React.ReactElement[]` or `JSX.Element[]` like this:

```
 const getItemList: Function = (groups: any[]): React.ReactElement[] => 
  groups.map((item: any, i: number) => {
    const itemCardElemProps = { key: item.id, handleEvents: () => {}, ...item}
    return <Item {...itemCardElemProps} />
  })
```

or you can rewrite it in the `interface` style:

```
interface IGetItemList {
  (groups: any[]): React.ReactElement[] // or JSX.Element[]
}

const getItemList: IGetItemList = groups =>
  groups.map((item: any, i: number) => {
    const itemCardElemProps = { key: item.id, handleEvents: () => {}, ...item }
    return <Item {...itemCardElemProps} />
  })
```

Comment: For me I noticed that if I do not declare `const getItemList` as a function as described in this answer, that the `JSX.Element` warning persists even if I define the function output as `JSX.Element[]`

Comment: super solution.

Answer (score 14):

@Roman They must have changed something, this doesn't work for me

code:

```js
const CardArray = (props: Items): JSX.Element[] => {
    return props.items.map((item) => <Item data={item} />);
};

export default CardArray;
```

error:

```
JSX element type 'Element[]' is not a constructor function for JSX elements.
Type 'Element[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Element': type, props, key
```

edit: nevermind, I just had to add the function type, to the function...
kind of stupid if you ask me.

what worked me:

```js
const CardArray: Function = (props: Items): JSX.Element[] => {
    return props.items.map((item) => <Item data={item} />);
};
```

Comment: This helped me as well. Don't understand why but thanks!

Comment: It resolved the same problem that I had with this.

Answer (score 8):

I was getting the error because of I am inheriting JSX.Element but I was using the .ts file extension. when I use the .tsx file extension my problem resolve.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error using this code:

```
let expensesContent = <p>No expenses found.</p>;

if (filteredExpenses.length > 0) {
    expensesContent = filteredExpenses.map((expense) => (<ExpenseItem expense={expense} key={expense.id} />));
}
```

The fix was to change the first line to:

```
let expensesContent: JSX.Element[] = [(<p>No expenses found.</p>)];
```

Answer (score -1):

I had an issue related to this error that may happen to other people. I'm new to TS and had the bad habit of using `[` and `]` to open and close the return JSX. As I just discovered TS doesn't allow it. So they should be replaced by `(` `)`

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You need to change the type of the function output from JSX.Element to **ReactNode[]** like this:

```
import { ReactNode } from 'react'

const getItemList: Function = (groups: any[]): ReactNode[] => 
    groups.map((item: any, i: number) => {
    const itemCardElemProps = { key: item.id, handleEvents: () => {}, 
     ...item}
    return <Item {...itemCardElemProps} />
})
```

Comment: `ReactNode` is never used in this code